# repeat selenium command line

Tags: python, selenium, loops

Good day, I am new in coding and have created a web automated script that logs into a specified web page. After logging in it I need to use a value from a span that displays/pops up numbers every second. Suppose the first number is `8.2165` and the one that follows it is `8.2984`.I have used the following line to print the number`a = print(driver.find_element_by_id('spot').text)`. How do I print the second number(`8.2984`) because if I type `b = print(WebDriverWait(driver,  1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'spot'))).text)` to wait one second to print the second number it still returns the same number`8.2165`.

Statement:: a = print('first number')
b = print('second number')

if a= 300.0 and b=6985
print('true')

Question:: how do I loop through the statement in Selenium Python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

1. `WebDriverWait(driver,  1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'spot')` doesn't wait 1s... it actually waits *up to* 1s for the element to become visible. It polls the DOM for the element every 250ms until the element becomes visible or times out. I think the issue you are running into is that on the second call, the popup is currently up so it meets the wait criteria so the same number is printed again.
2. The second issue is that you need to wait for the first popup to disappear and then wait for the second popup to appear. One way to do this is to wait for the first popup to become stale. A stale element is one that no longer is attached to the DOM (it no longer exists). The first popup will appear and then when it disappears, it will become stale or detached from the DOM. In order to wait for an element to become stale, you have to grab a reference to that element (store it in a variable) and then use `WebDriverWait` to wait for it to become stale.

On to the code...

```
# store the WebDriverWait instance in a variable for reuse
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)

# wait for the first popup to appear
popup = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'spot')))
# print the text
print(popup.text)
# wait for the first popup to disappear
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(popup))

# wait for the second popup to appear
popup = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'spot')))
# print the text
print(popup.text)
# wait for the second popup to disappear
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(popup))

... and so on
```

As you can see, the code is the same for each popup and so can be looped, if you wanted.

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

Comment: Hi JeffC I have been trying this method for quite sometime now and does not work. I think its because I did not write my question properly. Staleness seems to work if the whole span has been pulled from the DOM, but in this instance only the span value changes. in the code, Popup does not change, popup.text changes. Pleaetell me how do i correct this? When I enter staleness_of(popup.text) it returns error: __init__  str not enabled

Comment: @Moshe `staleness_of(popup.text)` is not in my code above. You will want to copy/paste my code into your project and try running it.